# Creating target variable column in test data set with "NA" values in R

Tags: r, error-handling, data.table, data-manipulation

I want to combine test and train data sets. Before which i have to add a new column to test dataset to match the number of columns of train data set.

I am creating a new column in test data set with "NA' values and this is the code i used:

```
test[,Item_Outlet_Sales := "NA"]
```

Compiling this code gave me this error:

```
Error in `:=`(Item_Outlet_Sales, "NA") : 
  Check that is.data.table(DT) == TRUE. Otherwise, := and `:=`(...) are defined for use in j, once only and in particular ways. See help(":=").
```

Comment: That's not R notation, did you mean `test$Item_Outlet_Sales=NA`?

Comment: `setDT(test); test[,Item_Outlet_Sales := "NA"]`

Comment: @user2974951 The package `data.table` brings the new notation. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html

Answer (score 2):

You just need to convert your data frame to data.table.

```
x[, X := NA]
Error in `:=`(X, NA) : 
Check that is.data.table(DT) == TRUE. Otherwise, := and `:=`(...) are defined for use in j, once only and in particular ways. See help(":=").
z <- as.data.table(x)
z[, X := NA]
```

Then you can see that the column called "X" is added.

In your case you just need to

```
test <- as.data.table(test)
test[,Item_Outlet_Sales := "NA"]
```

and add new column using := notation.

Comment: or in place `setDT(test)`

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)    
test <- test %>% 
      mutate(
            Item_Outlet_Sales = NA
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

code is fine, try this:
    `test<-data.table(test)`